# snmp/snmptrap support of ipv6

Tags: linux, ipv6, snmp

I have IPv6 only (not dual stack) system 
I wondering how to
 - send snmptrap from this system? 
 - configure snmpd to be able to access it?

I mean, is snmp is ready to use in IPv6 only environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to you have to specify **udp6**.

Sending: `trap2sink udp6:[::1]:162` in snmpd.conf
This will send to localhost IPv6.

Receiving: `snmptrapd udp6:162`

Answer (score 0):

First start snmptrapd to listen IPv6:

```
/usr/sbin/snmptrapd -On -Lsd -f -p /run/snmptrapd.pid udp:162,udp6:162
```

Then send a trap:

```
/usr/bin/snmptrap -Lo -v2c -c public udp6:[2001:db:8::beef]:162 "" .1.3.6.1.2.1.31337.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As root, I gave the command `/usr/sbin/snmptrapd udp:162,udp6:162` and that started the snmptrapd.  Verify that with the `ps -u root | fgrep snmptrapd` command.  Then, send a trap.  In my case, my IPv6 address is 2601:602:8500:1b2:5a74:16a3:770f:40ce so my command is `snmpinform -v 2c -m ALL  -c public 2601:602:8500:1b2:5a74:16a3:770f:40ce 145 coldStart.0` .  I have to use -m ALL because there's something wrong with how my MIB files are set up - I need to work on that.  If you get the error message "coldStart.0: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> coldStart)", then you might have the same problem I have - please, let me know.  If you don't get the error message, then leave out the -m ALL option.  coldStart.0 is one of the standard OIDs.  I don't what the OID is for this test.  What I *do* care about is the number 145.  Each time I give the `snmpinform` command, pick a different number, preferably larger.  That will make your life easier when tracing through log files.

This is not the best solution.  The best solution would be to use the

```
snmpTrapdAddr upd6:162
```

parameter in the /etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf file, which is the reason I came here in the first place.

If I have the snmptrapd set up correctly, then there will be an entry in /var/log/syslog that looks like:

```
Jan 10 02:04:35 jeffs-desktop snmptrapd[405089]: 2021-1-10 2:4 0.0.0.0 Cold Start
```